# transporter.sendMail() Could not execute in Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodemailer

email.js:

```
function send() {
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'test@gmail.com',
            pass: 'password'
        }
        });

        var mailOptions = {
        from: 'test@gmail.com',
        to: 'test@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Revenue Report',
        text: "Hello"
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent Successfully' + info.response);
        }
    });
}
 
module.exports = {
   send
}
```

```
var input = require('readline-sync');

var choice = input.questionInt("Enter Choice: ");

while (choice == 1) {
    var mail = require('./email.js');
    mail.send();
    break;
}
```

What I am trying to do is execute nodemailer to send an email to my gmail in a while loop. Although I can use if statement, I want to use while loop for other purposes, this is just an example.

In addition, I'm not sure why if statement is able to fully execute the code but not while loop. In while loop, the code just got stucked there and did not execute anything. However, in if statement, it got executed and an email was sent to my gmail.

That is just what I have found out during my troubleshooting process. I have researched and it says that I have to use async / await so that it will suspend the while loop and allow other events to process while waiting for the promise to resolve ? I don't quite understand that and was wondering if it can be done. Please help

```
async function send() {
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'ssam.tzh@gmail.com',
            pass: 'wervqojdwsnlgrzy'
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'ssam.tzh@gmail.com',
        to: 'ssam.tzh@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Revenue Report',
        text: "Hello"
    };

    const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
    console.log('Email sent Successfully' + info.response);
}

module.exports = {
    send
}
```

I have tried the code above but couldn't make it to work.

Comment: 1. `.sendMail()` uses a callback because network communication is asynchronous. 2. without that break; statement your code would attempt to send thousands of emails in a few milliseconds 3. here's a primer I wrote on async / await: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kpj204wL/

Comment: I'm just not sure where to include both async / await in the code because I am quite confused with it

Comment: Here's how to promisify: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/u4pg5Lbk/ (you only need to do this if the API doesn't support promises already)

Comment: I checked the docs and .sendMail already returns a Promise, **if** you don't pass a callback. Use `const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);`. Also, declare the function like `async function send() { ... }`

Comment: After the const info, where should I put my info at?

Comment: When I did this const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions); it says that "await" doesn't affect the statement of code.

Comment: ? First: `const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);` then: `console.log('Email sent Successfully' + info.response);` (also note that you should indent your properly, most editors can do this for you, try Alt-Shift-F for instance)

Comment: Im not sure what is going on but it doesnt work

Comment: I have edited my new solution above

Comment: To see what the problem is you need to  use a try catch block. Put the two lines from my last comment inside the try part, then put `catch (e) { console.error(e); }` below that. This should show you what goes wrong. Note that Google requires an app password to be set up, you cannot use basic email/pw auth.

Comment: I am aware of the app password part. However, it doesn't show me an error because it didnt prompt anything. The cursor just stays there like an infinite loop

Comment: Skip the choice part for now and just test your send code.

Comment: Yes, it does work

Comment: Is there any alternate solution to this?

Comment: I made a working example: https://github.com/khrismuc/mailexample

Comment: it prompted me an error :SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: My code only has await inside async functions.

Comment: I did what you suggested. Not sure why theres still an error

Comment: You really need to be more specific. We're talking about multiple issues here and I have no idea whether you actually cloned my repo, edited the env and mail file and ran the thing or did something else entirely. Given how extremely basic all of this is, we're both wasting time unless you tell me EXACTLY what you did and what the result is